# VS Code Extension: Is it possible to access View items using JS?

Tags: visual-studio-code, view, vscode-extensions

Your package.json creates a View in the Explorer, say "Test"...

```
"views": {
        "explorer": [
            {
                "id": "Test",
                "name": "Test"
            }
        ]
    }
```

... is it possible in the extension's JS to access that View?

Something like this...

```
ThisView=vscode.window.getViewById("Test");
```

Comment: And do what exactly with it? You can get access to a `TreeView` instance, but that doesn't have a list of items or anything like that. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeView

Comment: The idea was to dynamically control the contents of the View.  On further digging, it looks like the solution there is to create a Webview, not in package.json but in JS using createWebviewPanel.  Since this posting I got that working in an editor panel, but not yet in the side bar.  According to https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview a webview can be added to the sidebar.  Trying to figure that out.

Comment: What's not dynamic enough about the TreeView  approach with `getChildren()` and firing the `onDidChangeTreeData` event when needed?